# State of VLC for Android / Media Player that plays AVI files

Tags: video, htc-legend

Does anyone know where the VLC developers are up to with VLC for Android. Is there a beta out, an APK somewhere?

I'm trying to play an AVI on my HTC Legend, to no avail. If VLC is not ready, does anyone know a media player which will play AVIs (is there more than one codec for AVI types?).

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rockplayer](http://rockplayer.com) has decoders built-in and can play divX files. AVI files are containers - you should also find out what codec has been used for the video. Use a utility like [GSpot Codec](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) Information Appliance on your PC to check.

There's also [yxPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=kr.mobilesoft.yxplayer) but not too many satisfied users from what I hear although YMMV.

Comment: Thought that could be the case with the AVI file. Rockplayer worked a treat though. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been answered already but if someone else comes looking for Android video players here is an article on MakeUseOf that lists 8 of the "best" video players for Android:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/8-mobile-video-players-android-phone/

Answer (score 1):

Look for applications that use ffmpeg. It is something like an alternative set of codecs, and it handles quite a lot formats.

If I recall correctly, I used VitalPlayer once to play a Matroska file -- something which is not normally possible to do on my phone.

But it seems there are more programs that use this library.

Answer (score 0):

There's been a beta for VLC out for a while. You can find out about it on [the main Videolan site](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-android.html) or on their [Google Play site](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon).

I'm not sure of how it will play on your Legend, though.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried Arcmedia? Maybe that will work.